# Addition inside root problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

Help me calculate the answer for$$ \sqrt{3+\sqrt 5}\cdot \sqrt{3-\sqrt 5}$$ (NO CALCULATOR ALLOWED).
The answer in the book is "2" but I don't know how they solved it.

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt a\sqrt b=\sqrt{ab}$.

Comment: Hint: $(a+b)(a-b) = ? $

Comment: Haha no problem the hints were enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember these rules:

- $\sqrt A\times \sqrt B=\sqrt {AB}, ~ A,B≥0$
- $(A-B)(A+B)=A^2-B^2$

Then you can start:

$$\sqrt {A+\sqrt B}× \sqrt {A-\sqrt B}=\sqrt {(A+\sqrt B)×(A-\sqrt B)}=...$$